# Como imprimir el procedimiento de serie fibonacci?

Tags: java, variables, bucles, fibonacci

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Serie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scr=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n,f=0;
        int t1=1;
        int t2;
        System.out.println("Cuantos números de la serie quiere generar?");
        n=scr.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<= n;i++)
        {
            t2=f;
            f=t1+f;
            t1=t2;

            System.out.println(+t1);
        }
    }

}
```

Este codigo pregunta cuantos números se quieren de la serie y los imprime pero no se como hacer para que imprima las operaciones que dieron ese número 
El output que quiero es por ejemplo:
1+1=2
1+2=3
3+2=5
y asi sucesivamente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de que los primeros números de la sucesión son 0 y 1 (0+1=1, 1+1=2, 1+2=3, 2+3=5, ...)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Serie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner scr = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t1 = 0;
        int t2 = 1;
        int temp = 0;
        System.out.println("Cuantos números de la serie quiere generar?");
        int n = scr.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(t1 + "+" + t2 + "=" + (t1+t2));
            temp = t1;
            t1 = t2;
            t2 += temp;
            System.out.println(t2);
        }
    }

}
```

Pero si se quiere empezar a partir de 1 y 1 como en el ejemplo (1+1=2, 1+2=3, 2+3=5, ...) basta con cambiar el valor de la variable t1 a 1

Comment: Lo que busco es que me aparezcan las operaciones y el resultado,puede comenzar desde el 0

Comment: Si eso es lo que busco

Comment: Ya esta hecho solo había que agregar otro print

Comment: si el problema es que no se que variables imprimir

Comment: gracias por la ayuda